# New to MySQL Relationships

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mySQL relastionships and I'm wondering if you can help me out.

This is what I want to do:

***Users Table***

```
user_id

user_name

pass_word

permission_id
```

***Permissions Table***

```
p_id

permission_name

permission_type
```

I want to create a relationship between p_id (permissions table) & permission_id (user table) so when I query the user table it also brings through the corresponding permission name & type?

Is this possible or am I getting it all wrong?

Should I just use joins?

Thanks,

- WebDevB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from Users  u , Permissions  p  where u.permission_id = p.p_id;
```

[**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a `SELECT` query that will return all of this data that you want.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
INNER JOIN permissions p ON p.p_id = u.permission_id
```